# React State being reset without explicitly saying so

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, if-statement, firebase-authentication

I am making a small web app with react and firebase. My issue is that when the user logs in, the `isLoggedIn` state goes from `null` to `true` back to null and so Navigation bar cannot change to show that the user is logged in.

In `App.js`, I have cut quite a bit out for brevity:

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     isLoggedIn: null
    };
  }
```

As you can see `isLoggedIn = null` is the original state that I want to be changed to true, if user login is successful

```
 componentDidMount() {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: user.I})
  } 
 });
}
```

The above function in `componentDidMount()` is to handle the resetting of state if the page ever refreshes. It is a firebase function that supposedly fetches the last time the user was active and returns this state as a boolean value to whether the user is still logged in or not. Here, what I want it do is only set the state if the user is authenticated, if not, do nothing so that the user can log in.

```
handleLogIn = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
   .then((result) => {
     const isLoggedIn = result.user.I;
     this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
     });
   });
 }
```

This function allows the user to sign in via popup through Google which also returns a boolean value of whether the authentication was successful on that end or not, either way, I use this value to set the state.

```
render(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation
       {...props}
        isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
        handleLogIn={this.handleLogIn}
       />
    )
   }
  export default App
```

Lastly, I'm passing, these functions to my `Navigation.js` which is a functional component that only takes props. It looks like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navigation (props) {
  console.log(props.isLoggedIn)
  return (
    <ul className="tabs tabs-transparent">
     <li className="tab">
       <Link to="/">Home</Link>
     </li>
     <li className="tab">
    <Link to="/all_stories">All 
     Stories</Link>
     </li>
     <li className="tab">
    <Link to="/story/create">Write A 
    Story</Link>
    </li>
    {props.isLoggedIn ? (
       <div>
        <li className="tab">
          <Link to="/user/:id/profile">Profile</Link>
         </li>

         <li className="tab">
           <Link to="/logout" onClick={props.handleLogOut()}>Log Out</Link>
            </li>
            </div>
              ) : (
          <li className="tab">
         <Link to="/all_stories" onClick={(e) => props.handleLogIn(e)}>Log In</Link>
                  </li>
              )}
       </ul>
     );
    };
```

When I try to `console.log` the changing of state as the user goes through the login process, it looks like so:

[image: Null, Null, True, True, Null, Null]

What I would like to know is why is changing back all of a sudden at the last moment?

1. I originally thought it was the function occurring at the `componentDidMount()` but commenting that out had no effect
2. Another reason I thought there was an error was possibly because I was using a functional component, where if the expression returns null or undefined it would keep that value as the origin one, I was wondering if I did an if statement for the function to wait a certain amount of time before it ran, that it would be able to grab the `true` state again.

Thank you in advance

Comment: some suggestions: 1) in your `Navigation` component, you have this line: `<Link to="/logout" onClick {props.handleLogOut()}>Log Out</Link>`. Make sure that onClick includes an equal sign, like so: `<Link to="/logout" onClick={props.handleLogOut()}>Log Out</Link>`. 2) You are conditionally rendering a `div` within your list, then rendering `li`s within that `div`. The only children of list elements should be `li`s. 3) It may help to add more console logs to each component, so you can see in the console how many times each is being rendered. Ex: add `console.log("App: ", this.state)` to App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that this behaviour is caused by this line:

```
<Link to="/logout" onClick={props.handleLogOut()}>Log Out</Link>
```

Because you're calling `props.handleLogOut()` in `onClick` instead of giving it a function to call. You should be doing something like `onClick={props.handleLogOut}` or `onClick={() => props.handleLogOut()}`.

Here's what happens in your case:

1. You are not logged in. Thus `Link` to logout is not rendered and `props.handleLogout` is not called.
2. You are logging in and `props.isLoggedIn` becomes `true`.
3. `Navigation` component rerenders rendering this problematic `Link`.
4. `props.handleLogout` called resetting user to null.

That's just a kind of a typo.